# UISearchDisplayController lightbox doesn't cover tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, uitableview

I have gone through all the documentation I can find, but I just can't figure out how to solve this issue. When I click on the search text box, the lightbox comes up, but does not cover the whole screen (looks like it is off by ~64dp). Here are a couple of screenshots.

I have my search stuff inside of a tableViewController

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]
Has anyone had experience fixing this issue?

Here is how I am setting everything up:

```
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
self.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.searchBar.delegate = self;

self.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
self.searchController.delegate = self;
self.searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
self.searchController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;` in the viewDidLoad, and that messed EVERYTHING up...